# Where to turn for help when my 12-year-old granddaughter keeps hitting her 10-year-old sister?

Tags: pre-teen, siblings, grandparents, divorce, hitting

I have two granddaughters, one turns 12 in August, the other is 10 years old and is small for her age (she was a prem baby). Her parents are divorced since the older child was 5 and the dad has a new partner and child and has no interest in his girls.

The older one is for ever hitting her sister. This behaviour has been going on for years and she won’t stop. I have suggested to my daughter my older granddaughter needs counselling. My husband and I have talked to our older granddaughter to try to get to the bottom of this, but it keeps happening. My daughter has withheld privileges and it hasn’t made a difference. Her mother (my daughter) says she cannot cope with this anymore. We are all at our wits' end.

Has anyone dealt with this and what worked? To whom can we turn to for help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Parenting.SE! Please take the [tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you and your daughter already tried?

Comment: What steps has her mom taken to get her to stop?

Comment: Hi and welcome. This is a Q&A site, and we need an actual question. It is important to include more detail in order to get a useful answer. How does she explain this behavior? How has her mother tried to protect the child from these behaviors? Is there a therapist or counselor involved? Is anything (even temporarily) effective at stopping this behavior? Details matter! Thanks.

Comment: Hi and thank you for responding.

Comment: I should have asked to whom do we turn to for help. I have suggested to my daughter my gd needs counselling. My husband and I have talked to our gd to try to get to the bottom of this.but it keeps happening. My daughter has withheld privileges and it hasn’t made a difference. Has anyone dealt with this and what worked. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Lizzie, and thanks for commenting. Please edit this information into your answer (using the edit option under the behavior tag), as well as what the other questions have asked for. The question may well be reopened with this info. "To whom can we turn to for help?" may get some good information.

Comment: I really feel sorry for your situation. As pointed out by @anongoodnurse, it would be good to know how she justifies her behaiviour

Answer (score 5):

> Her mother (my daughter) says she cannot cope with this anymore. We are all at our wits' end.

I can well imagine. I deeply sympathize.

> Has anyone dealt with this and what worked? To whom can we turn to for help?

A *lot* of parents deal with this. A lot of parents don't know what to do anymore.

While I don't know all of what you've tried, I know it hasn't worked, and I also know that the 10 year old is being physically (and probably emotionally) abused by the 12 year old. **No one** deserves that kind of childhood and the pain they will carry into adulthood. It's time to step up efforts to stop this behavior.

1. **Get the 12 year old into counseling**. With so little information (how does she act at school? Is she a good student who gets good grades? Does she bully anyone? Is she being bullied? There is much to know which has not been supplied.) I don't even know which type of counselor to suggest, but a family therapist is probably a good start, as this involves the whole family. From there, the abuser may need some individual counseling as well.
2. In the US, we have **Crisis Intervention Hotlines**. You can call them for any number of problems, from suicidal thoughts to family dysfunction. They can help steer you to the right counselors/therapists as well, and can intervene until the meeting with the therapist. They can also assess the home situation and inform the therapist of issues the family may not consider a problem.
3. Find an intervention that affects the 12 year old. I don't know what has been tried, but keep trying and "make the punishment fit the crime". One thing that I believe should happen is that the older daughter should be sent to her room immediately upon striking *anyone*, protecting the other from any further abuse. She should stay there for a significant amount of time *without any means of communicating with the outside world.* She's there for three reasons: for reflection on her actions, to try to learn self control, and to prevent repeated abuse of the 10 year old. For the first two things to happen, she needs to think, not text and surf.

Though my tone is severe, I'm sure you love both children, and all this can be done in love. But get the child/family into therapy as soon as possible. Please don't let finding a therapist be an obstacle.

Comment: Good answer. One nitpick: For the "thinking" in your point 3 to occur, I guess you'd also have to remove books and maybe all other opportunities to lose yourself in play, wouldn't you? That seems difficult to achieve. I'm not disagreeing with the communications ban, I just think that you can't really get her to reflect on why she's confined to her room unless she *wants* to do it - you might create a context where it's more likely, but that's basically all, right? That's actually something I'm struggling with myself, so I'd be interested in some more pointers here.

Comment: Good point. One could send her somewhere more stark like the basement? Though that sounds barbaric at first (it sounds too much like a dungeon), it would probably cause more reflection on the consequences of her behavior. And you're right, you can't force someone to reflect on their behavior. One can only give opportunities and hope. And seek professional help if it doesn't help. But one must protect the abusee.

Comment: I tried that on a few occasions a few years ago with my oldest (not the basement, just a few steps down *to* the basement, which is even more boring). But I *did* feel bad about it, especially since it became clear quickly that he was afraid of being down there alone and I didn't want to use fear to teach, so I'm still looking for a solution that works.

Answer (score 3):

Sibling rivalry tends to be pretty common, and the reason it manifests is that, like everyone else, children have a need for love and when they're competing for it, they can feel a lot of resentment toward the person they're competing with. To bring into perspective how that can feel, imagine if your significant other suddenly got another wife (in a polygamous relationship) and you had to compete for his love and attention.

Now, you mention that the dad left and has no interest in his daughters, which I imagine might make it even tougher for the girls. Now they're competing for the limited time of a single parent and they've gone through the trauma of losing one parent's love.

So here's how I imagine the 12-year-old girl is feeling: **she NEEDS love and care from her mother, she's very angry that her sister is taking her mother's attention away from her, and maybe she's also afraid that her mom could lose interest in her, just like her dad did**. When her mother withheld privileges, her girl might have took that as a sign that she loves her less, which I imagine might have made the resentment stronger.

How to deal with this? There's an [article in Czech](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=cs&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nevychova.cz%2Fblog%2Fbyt-ten-druhy%2F) that I would recommend, but as it's in Czech, I'll try to summarize its recommendations (feel free to try Google Translate on it, though). When I say "you" here, I mostly mean the mother, though it's still applicable to you as the grandmother:

1) **Sit down with the older child and let her express herself openly** about the younger child. Don't judge. If she hates her sister, let her say that without passing judgment. And let her see that you understand her by repeating what she says ("You'd rather it be just you and me, huh?" or "So you really dislike it how much attention I give to your sister?").

2) **When the older daughter acts out, try to empathize and don't punish or yell**. Take her by the side and let her express herself, what she feels in the moment, and be empathetic. Once she's expressed herself fully, only then express yourself, but in a non-judgmental way — only by describing your own feelings (sad, angry, ...) and needs (peace, love, harmony, ...). The child should know that, even though you're not happy after what happened, you still love her.

(This might seem counterintuitive, but think back to the polygamous example. If you're really mad at your husband's other wife, the last thing you need is your husband yelling at you.)

3) **Plan some regular alone time with each of the children**, to let both know that they're still loved and to let them have some special time with the one they love.

Your daughter can try to do this alone, but sitting down with a child openly without judging can be tough to do in practice, especially when you're mad at them. So it might be better to go visit a good family therapist (make sure the therapist has a good track record) and let them mediate the interaction. That said, if your daughter doesn't want to go, then it's still worth it to try the solutions above.

Comment: Why do you not address the needs/feelings of the struck child? She is the one **being abused** in this situation. Pouring love on the abuser without addressing the wrongs done to the abusee? ("Peace, love, harmony" is all fine and good, but it does not take the sting away from the injustice of being struck for any reason.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Agreed, the younger child shouldn't be ignored, and that's not at all what I'm recommending here. The younger child needs to know that she is loved, too, and the mother needs to devote just as much time to her and empathize with her too. However, since the problem laid out here is the hitting that the older child is doing, my answer's focused on the older child, to help rectify that behavior.

Comment: The way that the wrongs are addressed is that you clearly express your feelings after they take place — your sadness and anger. Once the daughter understands how much she's hurting you, she'll be less motivated to hit her sister — she wants your love, after all. Punishments and yelling have the opposite effect.

Comment: Maybe she lacks empathy. Maybe she's a sociopath. Maybe she is a psychopath who enjoys hurting her sister. Who knows, unless she speaks to a therapist? I think the approach you take ('consider your husband brings home another wife; how would you feel?') is fine for young children. This situation is not brand new jealousy. It's downright malignant behavior. Contrary to the Beatles, Love is *not* all you need. Sometimes you need consequences and intervention.

Comment: I think these are excellent general ideas. Of course we should validate the victim as well, but that's not where our intervention is needed, so I think it makes sense that the post largely focuses on how to deal with the abuser. It's rarely the case that it's the victim who has received too little validation already. Failing this, professional intervention may of course still be called for.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - I know this seems nit-picky, but intervention is crucial for the victim, more so even than the perpetrator. The victim is truly the innocent party here, and needs protection. Without this being addressed, you've solved less than half of the problem.

Comment: @anon: sure, I don't have a reason to argue with that. I think "maybe she's a pycopath ... Who knows, unless she sperms to a therapist" is a bit of a stretch. That's true here, but mostly in the sense that it is for any of us, and we don't all go see a therapist just in case. The suggestions put forth here is how I would've approached this as well. I don't have a problem granting that other things may also need to happen, but that doesn't take away from this answer. I agree that the victim is truly innocent, but I think what's suggested here has a good chance of fixing the problem.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - Someone who continually hurts another and who knows they are hurting someone can very well be a psychopath. We don't ave any information to go by except for the most crucial bit: that they continually hurt another and have been doing it for years. We don't know why, what they feel, or anything else. To me, that is not a stretch to say she may be a psychopath.

Comment: Of the three suggestions, I like 3), but I think it's way too late for 1) and 2). The older daughter is hitting the younger one, and has been doing so *for years*. I think the time not to judge this behavior and let the older daughter express her feelings is long past. I'd second the "visit a good family therapist" suggestion.

Comment: It's been going on for years because apparently nobody has solved the root issue, which I am inclined to believe these suggestions stand a better chance of doing. If it is indeed the solution, it seems silly to conclude that it's too late for the solution.

Comment: For any of these 3 suggestions to work, what is needed is time. In my experience, kids don't stop recurring behavior that's repeatedly identified as unacceptable immediately, just because you have a good talk about it where you tell the child to open up and explain her feelings and then you talk about how that makes you feel. That may work in time (though I doubt it), but the hitting needs to stop quickly. I bet this "let's talk to find the root cause"-procedure will be part of counseling, too, but in addition to that, I'd think there'd come rules on how to immediately deal with hitting.

Comment: I'm all for a zero tolerance on violence. I still think that can be upheld while recognising that the problem behavior is likely a defunct means to an end. Replacing the need for violence is key, I think that's a much more constructive route forward than saying girl might be a psycopath, which isn't really a solution. If you think a therapist would say the same, then that speaks to their credit, but also to the credit of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big believer in "natural" consequences, and in this case, that would mean separating the girls immediately and consistently if they become physical with each other. "If you cannot treat each other with love and respect, you cannot play together." If necessary, this can extend to fun activities or rewards that are "only for children that play nicely with each other."

To make this work, you'll need to establish separable spaces for them. This can be difficult in a smaller home, but it doesn't need to be a full room --you can carve out smaller spaces in communal areas. Even a small zone to themselves can help ease tensions (even outside of the immediate incident).

Incidentally, this problem may not be as one-sided as it appears on the surface. It's far from unheard of for a smaller, weaker child to deliberately provoke an attack for the purposes of drawing sympathy, or of ensuring the other child gets punished (if my youngest complains of being attacked by my eldest, we've learned to always ask "what did you do first?") Fortunately, this approach works equally well no matter who is truly at fault.

Answer (score -6):

First of all, I am so sorry that you are all going through this. I know it can be a difficult situation, especially for the younger one who is the one of the receiving end.

I had a similar situation, although not that severe, with my now 6 and 3 year old. My 6 year old is a girl and the 3 year old is a boy. Well, she used to loveeee him when he was a baby. I mean she was crazy over him! Then he started to walk and start touching and trying to play with what she considered her toys. There were times when she would get aggressive against him. What helped was showing her how much it hurt him physically when she put her hands on him.

Like, lets say your older granddaughter slaps the younger one, then slap her back. Show her that this isn't a joke and she is actually hurting her sister. Just off the top of my head (I like to exaggerate things so my kids GET the point): Plan a day when the younger one can be out of the house, away from the eldest. Print a fake picture of a broken bone or something online and have mom sit down with the eldest and tell her that this is what happened because she hit her younger sister too much. Have an honest discussion as to why this is happening. Could it be that she misses her dad? Then have the younger sister come back a few hours later with a band aid or something (Kids wont know the difference) and hopefully she apologizes for her actions.. Again, you have my sympathy in this situation! Best of luck!

Comment: Do you really think a 12yo doesn’t know the difference between a cast and a band aid?!? Or needs to be hit to realize that hitting hurts? Sorry, but I don’t think you are on the right track here. Apart from that, the actual question is where to find professional help, which your post doesn’t address at all.

Comment: I read your other posts and would like to add a warning: the kind of exaggeration you suggest can backfire badly. Kids will at some point recognize it and then conclude (correctly, if we’re honest about it) that you lied to them. And that will undermine their trust and both your authority and credibility. Just imagine how a few years down the road you will want to warn your teenagers about e.g. drunk driving or safer sex - would you then want them to take your advice as “mom’s doing her exaggerating routine again”?

Comment: "Slap her back". Really? Hitting children is your child rearing advice?